# Evaluatinga triple integral

Tags: calculus, integration

we have a half-sphere 
$$V:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1,\ z\geq 0$$ 
for the function $f(x,y,z)=z$

$$\iiint_V f(x,y,z) \,dx\,dy\,dz$$

in my solution I tried to use sphere coordinates but I'm not able to get the same answer which is $pi/4$ and in my solution I  changed my variables to:

$$x=r\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi),\ y=r\sin(\theta)\sin(\phi),\ z=r\cos(\phi)$$
Jacobean is : $r^2\sin(\theta)$$$$$
my solution :

$$\iiint_V \cos(\phi)r^2\sin(\theta) \,dx\,dy\,dz =$$
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}  d\theta \int\limits_{0}^{1}dr \int\limits_{0}^{\pi} \cos(\phi)r^2\sin(\theta)d\phi...  $$ 
$$$$I'm getting the answer of zero :/ but it does not matter which integration order we use because the limits are constants so whats wrong with my soution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Limit for $\phi$ should be $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$ i.e. because the sphere is bounded below by $x-y$ plane and the angle from the $z-axis$ to the plane is $90^o$

Also limit for $\theta$ should be $0$ to $2\pi$ as if you collapse the sphere into the $x-y$ plane you get a full circle.

**Check** Jacobian is $r^2\sin(\phi)$

Comment: Jacobian has an $r^2$ term. An additional $r$ would come from $z$ which would make the power of $r$=3

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\iiint_V z\ dx\,dy\,dz
&=\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 (r\cos \phi)\ r^2 \sin \phi\ dr\,d\phi \,d\theta\\
&= \int_0^{\pi/2}\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 r^3 \sin \phi  \cos \phi \ dr \,d\phi \,d\theta\ =\ \ldots
\end{align}

Explanation: you're missing an $r$ from the $z$ component in the integrand. The angle from the $z$-axis to the $xy$-plane is a right angle and you have to form a full circle to get the whole upper half, if you integrate to $\pi$ you get a quarter of a sphere.

Comment: I get what you're trying to write here, but the formatting is pretty confusing. Parens would help, as would the align environment.

Comment: @Semiclassical I've never LaTeXed tripple integrals. Feel free to edit.

Comment: Ok, give me a minute or two...done, does that work for you?

Comment: @Semiclassical I'm on mobile, I don't get previews when posting and everything renders kinda bad here so I wouldn't really see a difference anyway. I trust you and I'm grateful you fixed it.